# Why are my Excel formulas not working as expected?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, vlookup

These are practice questions from a textbook. I'm trying to solve these questions using MS Excel. Attached are screenshots of the questions with examples I have tried below:

> [image: Sheet 1]

> [image: Sheet 1]

For total revenue, I used this:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!A2:D15,">=date(2018,2,1)),Sheet1!A2:D15, "<=DATE(2016,2,28),Sheet1!C:C,Sheet2!A5) but got #Value!
```

For revenue, I used this but got NA.

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet1!A2:D15,4,0)
```

I don’t know why I get errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the correct formulas and/or approaches or methods on how to calculate the correct values for these questions?

Comment: Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then edit your question.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please note we are not here to do your work for you. That said, if you have a specific problem with the answer you have attempted we'd be happy to have a look and point you in the right direction

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework.

Comment: No this is not a homework question. These are questions for practice I need anyone to provide suggestions to approach these

Comment: I already attempted the questions. I need someone to point me in the correct direction

Comment: Voting to reopen now that examples of formulas have been added.

Comment: For [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), remember that it searches the **first** column of the given range for the lookup value. But also remember that it only returns the **first** match.

Comment: For [SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b), it looks like you might have syntax errors regarding how you use the `DATE()` function, and also take note of the ranges for `Criteria_range1`, `Criteria_range2`, etc in your formula.